# TableView inside specific UICollectionViewCell programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

i am trying to add a TableView inside UICollectionViewCell, so i want to manage that cell by myself from TableView.
So to be more clear, if indexPath.row is 2, then i want to call my tableView cell's inside collectionview indexPath.row.

Please check the picture, i have made with red colour what i want to do.
I created everything programmatically, using UICollectionViewController and UICollectionViewControllerFlowLayout.

[image]

Comment: Where is the UICollectionView in this screenshot?

Comment: The screen is all UICollectionView, even if it's not looking like CollectionView.

Answer (score 8):

For those who need it, i found the solution:

```
class CustomizedCell: UICollectionViewCell, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var tableView = UITableView()
    let cellIdentifier: String = "tableCell"

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 4
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.value1, reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)

        cell.textLabel?.text = "1 CUP"
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Whole"

        return cell
    }
}
```

Then at viewDidLoad method at CollectionView i did this:

```
collectionView?.register(CustomizedCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

And after that i have called like this at cellForRowAt indexPath method of UICollectionView:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomizedCell

    return cell
}
```

Comment: I don't see when you add the `UITableview` to the collection cell?

Comment: Didn't this violate MVC pattern? Cells shouldn't know anything about data because they are just views

Comment: @TigranIskandaryan Only if you're using MVC, I guess. :^)

Comment: So how do you assign the data to the tableview in different collection cells??

Comment: @b-m-gevariya How did you among the height of the cells, both CollectionView and TableView cell?

Answer (score 3):

You can create a custom UICollectionView cell for that indexpath. And add a tableview in the cell xib.

Implement the delegate methods of tableview in custom cell class.

```
 class CustomCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate
  {
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    override func layoutSubviews() 
    {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }
  }
```

Comment: Is this implementation able to inherit the index of the CollectionViewCell itself?  Or do I need to obtain it via the CollectionViewDelegate protocol ??

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that's working for me.

```
import UIKit

class FirstCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    let cellId = "cellId"
    
    let tableView:UITableView = {
        let tableView = UITableView()
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return tableView
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = .blue
        
        addSubview(tableView)
        setUpViews()
        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0":tableView]))
        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0":tableView]))
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init is not done")
    }
    
    func setUpViews() {
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.register(MyCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId) 
    }
}

extension FirstCollectionViewCell: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! MyCell
        cell.label.text = "Testing testing"
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 40.0
    }
}

class MyCell:UITableViewCell {
    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        setUpViews()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    // creating a label to display some dummy text
    let label:UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "test"
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()
    
    func setUpViews() {
        addSubview(label)
        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0":label]))
        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0":label]))
    }
}
```

Comment: What if tableview cell has dynamic height

Answer (score 0):

The approaches above don't work well in with the MVC pattern. I recommend creating an NSObject subclass which conforms to UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource.

For example:

```
class DataProvider: NSObject, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    let dataManager = DataManager()
    let reuseId = "Cell"
    
    //MARK: - DataSource Methods
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataManager.data.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseId, for: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = .yellow
        return cell
    }
    
    //MARK: - Delegate Methods
    
}
```

Now in your UICollectionViewCell subclass you can specify the tableView data source and delegate properties, like so:

```
class ContainerCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    let dataProvider = DataProvider()
    
    let tableView: UITableView = {
        let table = UITableView()
        table.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return table
    }()
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
       super.awakeFromNib()
        
        addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.fillSuperview()
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: dataProvider.reuseId)
        tableView.delegate = dataProvider
        tableView.dataSource = dataProvider
    }
}
```

Perhaps not perfect, but achieves better encapsulation than the above answers.