# Tableview in scrollview when tableview content size increase then textview just below the tableview goes up to the tableview

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, ios-autolayout

I have Viewcontroller in which I set  the scrollview. In the scrollview I have tableview which is in the Container and just below the container I have an textview and some other UIViews when I set the tableview frame size equal to content size and tableview scroll property false so that only scrollview scrolls when the content size increase the textview goes up to tableview and I want that when tableview content increase then textview also goes down and parent view frame size increase and decrease as the content size [image: this is when content size is small]

[image: this is when content size increase]

Answer (score 1):

This look like a job for a UICollectionViewController. If you want to take a look [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview)

you can get a better understanding of what they are and how to use them. 
Basically you want to put each of those UITableViews, UILabels and the UIButtons in it's own cell(buttons need to be arranged) of the collectionView then the cell with the buttons try to use a stack view with the image. This will automatically set the different sections apart from each other. I know the idea of a collectionViewCell containing a tableView may seem weird but [check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43231937/tableview-inside-specific-uicollectionviewcell-programmatically)

Another solution is to get crazy with constraints and autoLayout. I don't recommend this route because autoLayout will make decisions on it's own if the exact layout is not explicitly declared. Basically you'll set the constraints by pinning the tableView and labels to each other and the container they are in.
Checkout Apple's docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html)

Good luck and let me know how it goes

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a xib (if storyboards is your preference) or programmatically embed a tableview in the Scrollview Controller. Set a default cell height and then calculate the height of the Tableview by grabbing the amount of cells (which you'll normally get from .count in an array).

Afterwards, constrain the top, left, and right constraints of the tableview to its parent. You can imbed these in a scroll view for ease. Then if you want default text underneath it, all you have to do is constrain the top of the textview to the bottom of the tableview.

Do the cell for the button's. As the post above said, buttons might be best done in a CollectionView, so you can either create a default cell (xib again is useful) or use a prototype cell in storyboard. Collection views are the same principle as tableviews when it comes to populating data, they are just formatted differently and insets/spacing between cells.

This should help!