# How to add a button dynamically in collection view and name it dynamically from user input (Swift 4)?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I am trying to create a notes app

In which there will be a collection view and user can type category name and click ok, and it will be added to the array and listed as last item in collection view.

How do I implement button in collection view and make it clickable to display tableview (To list sub item list)

Comment: Hello, could you please provide more details of what you already tried.
Now you are asking for a prototype.
Please, refer to the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section for more info about asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TableView inside specific UICollectionViewCell programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43231937/tableview-inside-specific-uicollectionviewcell-programmatically)